# what does 'But to the kid' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

while reading a medium article I encountered this expression, don't know exactly what it means:

> Seinfeld, a pure stand-up, a comedian’s comedian, is appalled by the question. It’s offensive to his legendary heads-down work ethic. **But to the kid**, this was a surprise. Isn’t that the kind of question you’re supposed to ask? Isn’t that how you get ahead?

Comment: It's just a stylised resequencing of what would normally be expressed as ***But this was a surprise to the kid*** (which arguably emphasizes that *the kid* found it surprising, even though perhaps many others wouldn't, by placing that "important" element in a position where it tends to stand out and be noticed more).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be clearer this way:

> Seinfeld, a pure stand-up, a comedian’s comedian, is appalled by the question. It’s offensive to his legendary heads-down work ethic. This was a surprise **to the kid**. Isn’t that the kind of question you’re supposed to ask? Isn’t that how you get ahead?